# Merge premade plot_ly objects

Tags: r, r-plotly

I have two plotly objects that are output from 2 separate functions.  I would like to merge these two plotly objects to create a single plot using the same axis (overlaid on each other).  The catch is that I need to merge the two preexisting plotly objects instead of adding a trace based on the source data frame.  This is something I can't get around due to some firm requirements I have for the output format of the functions.

I have tried to use the subplot command, but that results in two side by side plots.  A greatly simplified example is:

```
a = as.data.frame(cbind(1:10,1:10))   #example data 1
b = as.data.frame(cbind(1:10,11:20))  #example data 2

p1 = plot_ly(a, x = ~V1, y = ~V2)     #plotly object 1
p1 = plot_ly(b, x = ~V1, y = ~V2)     #plotly object 2

p3 = subplot(p1,p2, shareX = TRUE, shareY = TRUE)
```

Ultimately, I want to create a plot out of the two plotly objects, that looks the same as the plot created with the following command:

```
p3 = add_trace(p1, x = b$V1, y = b$V2)
```

Thank you for any help you can give.